# Email When A Program Is Closed?

Tags: windows, email, notifications

Is there any program I can run, that, when another program or service is quit that it will send an email notification?  Something for Windows machines

We have a building automation program that we would like to have running at all times.  We just want to be alerted by email if the program gets closed.

Thank you

Comment: Don't fall in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), explain what problem you are trying to solve and you are much more likely to get better answers to do whatever you are trying to do. Are you doing this for security? Are you doing it because you want to make sure a program is always running? Are you wanting to start a long running program and be notified when it is finished? Add more details of what you are trying to accomplish and you will get much more useful answers.

Comment: We need something that will notify us if our building automation program happens to get closed or crashes.  We just need a notification as soon as the computer notices the process is no longer running.

Comment: You should edit your original question and include information like that. Also include details about the program. Is it running as a service or as a user program? Can the program be changed to run as a service if it is not currently?

Answer (score 3):

A script can be written to do this.  My examples are for VBScript.  Here is a [Script](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_process.htm) to List the Processes Running on the Computer.  And here is a [script](http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/46-add-send-email-to-any-vbscript) to send an email.  You can combine the two, make some tweaks and a loop, checking for a process and emailing if it does not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Restarter](http://www.knas.se/Applications/Restarter.aspx):

- Monitors a specified Process existence
- Restarts and/or logs when the process fails, crashes or **is accidentally shut down**
- Automatically kills the monitored process if it is unresponsive or hung
- Option to execute external scripts if the process fails. **Sample scripts includes Send e-mail**, Restart Computer
- Option to play a selectable sound when process fails.
- Option to restart the process window Maximized, Minimized or Normal
- Option to force focus on the restarted process window
- Option to start your application from a shortcut and automatically have it monitored with Restarter
- Portable application - No registry settings & all program files in one single directory, making it suitable to run directly from a memory stick

[image: 1]